# Redis modelling

Tags: redis

What is the best way to model the following scenario? User has multiple portfolios, each with multiple stocks.

I have come up with the following:

Stocks will be in a hash as below

stk:1 {name:A, ticker:val, sector:val ..}
stk:2 {name:B, ticker:val, sector:val ..}

Users can be a hash as below: (is it better to store portfolios for a user seperately as a set?)

user:1 {k1:val1, k2:val2, portfolios:"value|growth|short term"}
user:2 {k1:val3, k2:val4, portfolios:"value|defensive|penny"}

Stocks in a portfolio can be sets
user:1:value (1,3)
user:2:value (2,3,4)
user:1:short term (1,5)
user:2:penny (4)

In order to add/remove a portfolio for a user, its required to 'HGET user:n portfolios' followed by a HSET

Is this a good way to model as the number of users and portfolios grow?

Answer (score 4):

If a user can have multiple portfolio types then it would be best to separate them into their own sets.

```
sadd user:1:portfolios value growth "short term"
```

This makes removing a portfolio from a user as simple as calling `srem user:1:portfolios value` on the set (and of course removing the "user:ID:TYPE" set).

When you want to lookup stocks for a user based on portfolio type you can do so using the `sunionstore` and `sort` command (example in Ruby):

```
keys = redis.smembers('user:1:portfolios').map do |type|
  "user:1:#{type}"
end

redis.multi do |r|
  r.sunionstore "user:1:stocks:_tmp", *keys
  r.sort "user:1:stocks:_tmp", get: ["stk:*->name", "stk:*->ticket"]
  r.del "user:1:stocks:_tmp"
end
```

`stk:*->name` will return only the hash values for `name`. If you want to get all entries in the hash specify each of them using the 'KEY->HASHKEY' syntax.

http://redis.io/commands/sort

Answer (score 2):

There is no best way to model something: it all depends on your access paths.

For instance, your proposal will work well if you systematically access the data from the user perspective. It will be very poor if you want to know which users have a certain stock in their portfolios. So my suggestion would be to list all the expected access paths and check they are covered by the data structure.

Supposing you only need the user perspective, I would rather materialize the portfolios as a separate set, instead of storing a serialized list in the user hash: they will be easier to maintain. Because you can use pipelining (or scripting) to run multiple commands in a single roundtrip, there is no real overhead.